# Negative Voltage Ccfl Inverter from AC Adapter

Tags: inverter, negative, ccfl

I have a CXA M10M-L ccfl inverter and I need negative voltage from its output, for anode ground scheme of a photomultiplier tube. I am confused because most discussions of this topic use batteries to explain, but I would likely use a 24v AC adapter. I read a post where grounding the positive leaves the ground pin at the same voltage but is then negative, but wouldn't the ground pin already be grounded via the AC adapter's negative wire? I will have full wave rectification right after the positive pin, before any other circuitry, because this has to be DC.... or do I put it somewhere else for negative?

http://www.tpub.com/neets/book1/chapter3/1-38.htm
-I understand this topology but would the center ground need to have a shorter path to the actual ground wire in the earth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using batteries to explain relative voltages for various connections is legitimate *if* the power-supplies have isolated outputs. If, as you fear in this case, the output ground or common is connected to mains earth then this would not be the case. To figure this out we need to study the [datasheet](http://www.tdk-lambda.com/products/sps/catalog/eng/etl_cxa_m10m_l.pdf).

[image]

*Figure 1. From page two of the datasheet we can see that input and output grounds are named differently as GND and OUT GND. This is our first sign of hope that the supply is isolated.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Page 3 lists various connection configurations. The naming convention is continued here but there is no additional information.*

Based on Figures 1 and 2 it looks likely that GND and OUT GND are isolated. You can confirm this with a (dis)continuity check using your multimeter. If there is no connection then you are free to connect the + output to your circuit common.

Note that even if there is a through connection you could supply the device from an isolated 24 V PSU and there would be no ground reference.

If any of this needs further elaboration then please add a block diagram or schematic in your original post and comment below to let me know. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: OUT GND connects directly to GND, so this means it is not isolated? And therefore an isolated PSU would make it so that I can have negative circuitry between the parallel to ground, and the negative?

Comment: That's a surprise then and a good job you checked. Yes, an isolated 24 V PSU will remove any ground return paths through the rest of your circuit. Just make sure it can supply enough current.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier then to use three 9volt batteries in series and a voltage divider to get the same thing?

Comment: (1) I assumed you wanted mains power. (2) A voltage divider wastes power. A voltage regulator would be better.

Comment: Well I thought mains was easier, and would rather not need a battery change in the middle of lots of other active HV wiring, but I'll just check batteries before each use. I'll plan on connecting series batteries into a voltage regulator. Can I have a parallel connection at the positive 1200v output before I do any negative circuitry business? Because I need a voltage divider to +250v for the tiny faraday cage on it

Comment: Start a new question and provide a schematic. There's a button on the editor toolbar. Text is not a good way to describe a circuit. You can accept this answer if it answers the original question.